# asp.net razor pages: why is my model not altered in my ActionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am showing some checkboxes in my page.

```
var lang = new LanguageManager().GetItems().ToList();
foreach (var item in lang)
{
    var res = new CheckedLangs
    {
        Name = item.Name,
        Id = item.Id,
        isChecked = false // todo
    };
    CheckedLanguages.Add(res);
}

<div class="divFormField">
    <table cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">
                <label for="position">Sprachen</label>
            </td>
            <td class="Field">
                <table>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckedLanguages.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="js-export-checkbox">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CheckedLanguages[i].Name)
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedLanguages[i].isChecked)
                                <label>@Model.CheckedLanguages[i].Name</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

They are displayed correctly. I see the text on them, and they all are set to false, so none of the boxes are checked.

If I check one, the first one for instance, and then check my model in the ActionResult I get this:

[image]

Its a list of all my checkboxes, with all the properties.
But whats missing is that even though I checked one of the boxes, they all still have the value of "false" after I click save.

I must be missing one vital thing here. But I cant seem to find it?
Can you help me out here?

Comment: Did you inspect what your client posted to the server, using your browser's developer tools, network tab? Does that clue you in on what went wrong?

Comment: this is a bit hard, as the frontend is part of a popup that closes upon networks state changes... so you would also say I did everything right, or?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="model.CheckedLanguages[@i].isChecked" value="true"/>
```

to replace

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedLanguages[i].isChecked)
```

Or you can try to set the default values of `Model.CheckedLanguages[i].isChecked` with true.

Comment: Ofcourse I can change the default, but I need to get the changes the user makes on tzhe frontend after he clicked "save". I tried your other solution, but it still give me back all my defautl checkboxes, even when I check them...